# How to compare elements in dynamic

Tags: prolog

I have two `dynamics` of /2.

One of the lists, lets call it D2 has set values inside of it. For example: 2 and 3, 4 and 5.

How can I check if my dynamic 1  aka. D1 has all the values inside of it that D2 has and then return true if it does?

I tried to use

```
member(E, D1(_,_)), member(E, D2(_, _)). So far but without much luck.
```

Comment: What do you mean by a *dynamic*? Do you mean a dynamic database fact, which you assert or retract during the course of your program? `D1(_,_)` isn't a list, so `member(E, D1(_,_))` doesn't make any sense. Also, `D1` and `D2` are variables since they begin with a capital letter. Did you intend for these to be atoms (`d1` and `d2`)? You cannot have a fact or a predicate that has a variable for a name, such as `D1(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty icky as far as data models go and whatever it is you're trying to do with this is going to *at least* be inefficient, if it can even be made to work. You'd be far better off defining an arity 3 fact with the first arg being an atom that identifies the type.

That said, you can probably do enough introspection to handle it.

```
dif(Q, P), 
predicate_property(QR, dynamic), 
predicate_property(PR, dynamic), 
QR =.. [Q, _, _], 
PR =.. [P, _, _].
```

This says, find me two predicates with arity 2, whose heads are different. Ideally, you want just the user-defined predicates. SWI-Prolog cannot do this, but GNU Prolog can, you could add some extra constraints:

```
predicate_property(QR, user), 
predicate_property(PR, user),
```

This is my solution:

```
matching(Q, P) :- 
    dif(Q, P),                                % different predicates, please
    predicate_property(QR, dynamic),          % both dynamic
    predicate_property(PR, dynamic),
    QR =.. [Q, Q1, Q2],                       % arity-2 predicates, please
    PR =.. [P, P1, P2],
    findall([Q1, Q2], clause(QR, true), Qs),  % find all facts (:- true)
    findall([P1, P2], clause(PR, true), Ps), 
    forall(member(PV, Ps), member(PV, Qs)),   % ensure the fact sets are equal
    forall(member(QV, Qs), member(QV, Ps)).
```

Please, please, *please* **DO NOT DO THIS!**

Comment: I imagine I will have to find a better way to hold my data for what I want. But the solution is working. Performance is not a concern for my case right now. Thanks!